# How to add visual studio 5 project in visual studio 3?

Tags: visual-studio-2003

I have opened a project created in visual studio 3 in visual studio 5 unknowingly. So when I am trying back to open that project in visual studio 3, it is not getting opened and also showing an error saying

> THE SELECTED FILE IS VISUAL STUDIO SOLUTION FILE, BUT WAS CREATED BY A
>   NEWER VERSION OF VISUAL STUDIO AND CANNOT BE OPENED.

What can I do to open the file in visual studio 3?

Thanks in advance!!!!

Comment: They made a big thing of the fact, when VS 2012 came out, that it was possible to round trip between 2012 and 2010. Which is another way of saying that such round trips weren't possible with earlier versions. Also, VS2003 has fallen out of even *extended* support, as have the versions of .NET framework that it works with, so it really is time to upgrade.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't have a backup of the project files, perhaps you can use [the Visual Studio Project Converter](http://sourceforge.net/projects/vspc/) to recover your project.

From the link:

[image: description]

I have to say that these versions of Visual Studio are now very much out of date - it might be better to just upgrade everything to VS2013.